# How do I open a link from an email in mutt (without using the mouse)?

Tags: keyboard, mutt

One of the things I like about using Mutt is that I don't have to use the mouse pretty much at all. I get a lot of emails that contain links, though, whether they're validation ("click on this link to validate your account") or from Facebook or other similar sites. What I want to know is, is there a way to open these links without clicking on them?

Answer (score 15):

I also want to advise using [`urlscan`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/urlscan.1.html) instead of `urlview`. Its man page explains what needs to be added to your .muttrc to get it to display your email links. I found it to be better than `urlview` for two reasons:

1. It does not truncate URLs like `urlview`.
2. It also displays the text in the context of which the URL occurs, which is very helpful when you have an email with many links. In my experience, `urlview` doesn't do this.

I recently made this switch and have found mutt to be a lot more usable when it comes to opening links from it.

Comment: The last version that is Python 2 compatible is 0.9.3. Requires: Python 3.3+ and the python-urwid library.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the easiest method is with the [`urlview`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/urlview1.html) helper utility for mutt. The urlview utility is a curses program designed to be a URL extractor and launcher. The method of installation depends on your target operating system. It can be obtained from the [mutt ftp site](ftp://ftp.mutt.org/pub/mutt/contrib).

Once installed, place this in your `~/.muttrc`:

```
macro pager \cb 'urlview' 'Follow links with urlview'
```

You can now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to launch urlview in the pager.

Comment: I had to actually have `macro pager \cb <pipe-entry>'urlview'<enter> 'Follow links with urlview'` to get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `urlview` is `w3m`, a text based web browser and pager.

```
macro index,pager \cb ": unset wait_key; set pipe_decode\n|w3m\n: set wait_key; unset pipe_decode\n" "call w3m to extract URLs out of a message"
```

After typing Ctrl-B to launch `w3m`, type `:` (a colon) to tell `w3m` to convert URL strings to links.

You may also want to w3m's Option Setting Panel (type `o`) and set the "Treat URL-like strings as links in all pages" to YES.  Then you won't have to keep typing `:` as you page through the message.

Comment: Is there a way to then open the w3m links in, say, firefox, instead of staying in w3m?

Comment: Yes. Open `w3m`, type `o` to open the Option Setting Panel, scroll down to "External Program Settings" and set the "External Browser" or "Second External Browser" to "firefox". Select "OK" to save the setting. To use the External Browser, type `M` to view the current page or `<Esc>M` to follow a link; to use the Second External Browser, type `2M` or `2<Esc>M`.

Comment: Thanks. However, it doesn't seem to be working for me. There may be more troubleshooting involved, so I've asked a proper [question](https://superuser.com/questions/983201/how-can-i-open-links-from-w3m-in-firefox-redux).

Answer (score 0):

A no-plugins alternative (hackish).

```
macro index,pager gu "| grep -Eom1 '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-&]*' > /tmp/mutt_url; google-chrome $(cat /tmp/mutt_url); rm /tmp/mutt_url<enter>"
```

Pressing gu will find the first url in a highlighted or open email (by grepping for http, change it to whatever you feel is appropriate in your situation) and opening it in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Answer tested Fedora 35 with mutt email 2021, how to view links in mutt that span over multiple lines.

1.Install and Setup Urlview
Specify what you want urlview to open your links with in ~/.urlview after COMMAND. I.e. the line below will make urlview open all urls in Firefox.

COMMAND firefox

2.Enter this line in muttrc

macro index,pager U "set pipe_decode = yesurlviewset pipe_decode = no""view URLs"

3.Run mutt push CTR B on email for list of links contained within it.
Click enter on link you want to view and enter again to launch link in web browser.